# binary format that allows to store multiple pandas dataframes with different columns, width, rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet, orc

I have like 200 pandas dataframe, and every dataframe has some unique column, or maybe completely different columns. example:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Mango'],
    'Quantity': [10, 15, 12, 8],
    'Price': [2.5, 1.5, 2, 3],
    'Category': ['Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Fruit']
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Student Name': ['John', 'Emma', 'Lisa', 'Tom'],
    'Age': [18, 17, 19, 18],
    'Grade': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
    'City': ['New York', 'London', 'Paris', 'Sydney']
})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    'Company': ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'AMZN', 'MSFT'],
    'Price': [132.69, 1760.33, 3187.50, 215.41]
})
# and many more
```

while I thought that I can easily jump into Parquet and make a one folder, this turned out that it doesn't work that way if the Parquet files has different schemas (*I haven't implemented it, so maybe I'm wrong too*)

obviously I have read this post [Storing multiple dataframes of different widths with Parquet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456673/storing-multiple-dataframes-of-different-widths-with-parquet)

**so what are some of the formats that allow storing multiple dataframes in one file?** *other that excel*

note: I'm trying to look into `to_orc()` and `orc` format, but I don't know if I can merge different schemas and cutoff `NA` values.

note2: maybe it's not an answerable question, but you can help with sharing topics and links.

Answer (score 1):

> **so what are some of the formats that allow storing multiple dataframes in one file?** *other that excel*

You can use [HDF5](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-hdf5). Install [`pytables`](https://www.pytables.org/) first with `pip install tables`

```
with pd.HDFStore('dataframes.hdf') as store:
    df1.to_hdf(store, key='df1')
    df2.to_hdf(store, key='df2')
    df3.to_hdf(store, key='df3')
```

Check:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('dataframes.hdf')

>>> store.keys()
['/df1', '/df2', '/df3']

>>> print(store.info())
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: dataframes.hdf
/df1            frame        (shape->[4,4])
/df2            frame        (shape->[4,4])
/df3            frame        (shape->[1,3])
```

Comment: I've looked at it and worked with some examples that I have. but strangely, the final file doesn't to be compressed enough. *maybe I still don't know how to optimize it*.
the thing that made my jump into `parquet` is that we've optimized a lot of our dataframes using `pyarrow` engine, which looking at `hdf`, it doesn't seems it can benefit from that.